# The method eth_sendTransaction does not exist/is not available

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, web3js, truffle

I am trying to send the args on function from owner account but getting Returned error.

I am using [web3 1.0](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/blob/1.0/dist/web3.min.js) .

Function in contract :

```
/**
* @dev Adds single address to whitelist.
* @param trusted Address to be added to the whitelist
*/
function addToWhiteList(address trusted) public onlyOwner {
    require(!whitelist[trusted]);
    whitelist[trusted] = true;

    emit UserWhitelist(true);
}
```

Code on index.html :

```
// Add user on whitelist
abc.methods.addToWhiteList("0x9DA80947ACf5Fc16299311EdAabc37fF7d201C95")
.send({ from: "0x61A44075419C4402f6DE631341d875Ece6A3922e" })
.on("receipt", function(receipt) {
  console.log(receipt);
})
.on("error", function(error) {
  console.error(error);
});
```

**ERROR :** `Returned error: The method eth_sendTransaction does not exist/is not available`

**Note :**
I add web3 in script tag :

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="web3.min.js"></script>
```

and init. like this :

```
web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider("wss://ropsten.infura.io/ws"));
```

Comment: Your code seems to be perfect. Maybe something is broken with Inura. I hope you are unlocking seders add before sending tx.

Comment: @PrashantPrabhakarSingh, I didn't get you. I am sending tx. from owner account and  I add the owner public key in from .

Comment: You need to unlock the owner's account. Check `personal.unlock(owner)`

Comment: @PrashantPrabhakarSingh, I tried but didn't get any success.
Can you please let me know in separate answer so I can accept your answer also.

Comment: Infura doesn't support `sendTransaction` you have to sign your own transactions and use `sendSignedTransaction`, or use a plugin like MetaMask to sign transactions.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is the reason. But try unlockking account before sending transaction. The senders account needs to be unlocked. Generally you get `please unlock your account` error. But may be this is not allowing you to send tx. A sample code looks like:

```
    custom_func.prototype.SENDCNK=function(from,to,password,amount){
    return new Promise(function(fullfill,reject){
        /* add basic checks like if user has sufficient balance , address are valid etc*/
        web3.eth.personal.unlockAccount(from, password).then(function(result,e){
            console.log("Account "+from+" unlocked successfully");
            amount = parseFloat(amount);
            amount = amount *decimalMultiplier;
            cnkContract.methods.transfer(to ,amount).send({from:from})
                .on('transactionHash',function(txHash){
                    console.log("Transaction hash : "+txHash);
                    fullfill(txHash);
                }).catch(function(error){
                    console.log("Unable to send transaction. Error:"+error);
                    logger.error(error);
                    reject("Sending transaction on blockchain failed");
                });        
       }).catch(function(error){
            logger.error("Incorrect transaction password for account: "+from);
            reject("Incorrect transaction password.");
       });
    });    
}
```

Comment: I tried like this : web3.eth.personal.unlockAccount("0x61A44075419C4402f6DE631341d875Ece6A3922e", "12egjec308").then(function(result,e) {
      console.log("Account unlocked successfully");
    });

but still getting error :  Returned error: The method personal_unlockAccount does not exist/is not available

Comment: The reason for this is you need you need to enable perosnal api over rpc (by default this is disabled for security reasons). When you set-up geth you enable this under rpc flag like `--rpcapi web3,eth,net,personal,db`. If you don't enable this you cann't access personal methods. Since you are using infura node, check if they have enabled the same.

Comment: If you are doing testing and all, I shall recommed setup a private node which will be under yiur control to test your app better. You can check my medium post [here](https://medium.com/@prashantprabhakarsingh/setting-private-blockchain-with-ethereum-and-geth-7c68760e939) for same.

Comment: Thanks for your words ! But thing is that want to test on infura node ?

Comment: Then you need to check if they are exposing personal over rpc.